# How do I sync extensions and their settings between VS Code profiles?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking to optimize my coding workflow and have decided to use Visual Studio Code profiles for different coding environments such as web, Python, Java, etc. However, I want the profiles to share some extensions and their settings to avoid redundancy and maintain consistency. Is there a way to achieve this?

Specifically, I would like to have a centralized location to modify the shared extensions and settings, so they are kept up-to-date across all profiles. Is this possible in Visual Studio Code?

The [docs page about profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) only mentions that you can export profiles to a Gist, but I haven't found a way to directly append settings from a Gist to a profile.

Comment: out of curiosity, what kinds of settings are you having differ between profiles? If they're settings that have to do largely with specifics of workspace folders, you could just use a user settings.json file and workspace settings.json files (see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings).

Comment: @user I mostly just want to disable unnecessary extensions and their settings to make vscode startup a bit faster. Workspace settings can't disable extensions afaik, so they aren't the solution.

Comment: then this is indeed a XY problem. You can already enable/disable extensions per-workspace. Go to the extenions sidebar, click the gear icon for an installed extension, and you will see options like "Disable (Workspace)" and "Enable (Workspace)". Just disable the extension globally and then enable it in each workspace where you want it enabled. That's what I do for all my language-specific extensions. See also [the `extensions.json` file docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions).

Comment: The title was misleading, sorry. I guess disabling them per-workspace is the best solution currently. It doesn't still sync the extension status on similar workspaces, so I would have to manually enable new extensions on each workspace.

Comment: I'm glad I found this. I have tons of extensions. I develop IoT devices which I only use C/C++. I have a lot of C/C++ extensions. I develop Dart/Flutter for apps, again extensions for Flutter. I develop Python scripts and Django sites with lots of web extension for js, vue.js, css. I have a core of extensions I always use. Would be nice to have JSON file that I can just copy over to each profile that auto installs those extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want something akin to what's proposed in this feature-request issue ticket on VS Code's GitHub repo: [Profiles: Extend from Default Profile #156144](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156144):

> One idea we are considering is to allow users to choose between following options while creating a profile:
>
> - Extend from Default Profile
> - Diverge from Default Profile
>
> When chosen to extend, settings from default profile are applied unless user overrides them in the profile.

<sup><sub>[You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Submitting-Bugs-and-Suggestions) "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup>

The issue ticket is in the iteration plan for June 2023 ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156144#issuecomment-1588626329)).  Update: there is now a "partial profiles" feature in VS Code Insiders. ([More info here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156144#issuecomment-1640284109)), and a `workbench.settings.applyToAllProfiles` setting.

Also related for a more general case: [Add ability to extend from other settings files #15909](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15909).

You can also go on a per-setting basis in the settings UI by clicking a setting's gear icon and selecting "Apply Setting to All Profiles".

Answer (score 3):

" I want the profiles to share some extensions and their settings to avoid redundancy and maintain consistency."

You can install an extension to ALL profiles today in Insiders.  See [How to install a vscode extension for all profiles (profiles not users!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76696051/how-to-install-a-vscode-extension-for-all-profiles-profiles-not-users/76696103#76696103)

You can do the same thing with settings:

[image: apply setting to all profiles]

Hover over the setting and click on the Gear icon that appears.  To stop the setting from being applied to future profiles, hover over the setting and click the `Apply Setting to all Profiles` option to disable/uncheck it.

##### Important: Modifying the setting in any profile - while that setting is shared among profiles - will update that setting in ALL profiles.  You would have to disable the sharing of the setting to separately set it to different options in different profiles.

Comment: It seems to be implemented in a way that semantically seems to work a lot like symlinks - instead of a setting, you have a reference to where the setting is configured.