# Add/change setting for all profiles and workspaces in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a settings file that will apply to all profiles and all workspaces, assuming you use profiles and don't just stick with the default ? I assumed the user profile at `user-data\User\settings.json` would act as a default unless a profile overrides it, but instead it seems every profile has its own 'User' settings file.

Comment: If you'd like to post an answer about the 'apply to all profiles' aspect of it, I'll happily accept it, otherwise I would prefer to auto-answer instead of closing this one - I would have never found the question you linked, because I thought about it in different terms, and I think future readers looking for a solution in my sense would also not end up at the linked question. The partial profiles aspect is nice, but not really suitable for my case - I didn't want to override ALL settings or a whole group, just individual ones (bookmark settings, vertical lines at 80 chars, etc)

Comment: If possible, I would prefer to duplicate link go to the non-accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76732352/1202894 which seems more relevant to my specific question, but if that isn't possible, hopefully these comments will be enough

Comment: duplicate links go to _questions_ not particular answers to those questions. readers can determine which answer is helpful to them on their own. If you agree that an answer there is useful here, then please comply with the duplicate closure.